# In Xbox One Elite:Dangerous can you fire chaff outside a fire group

Tags: elite-dangerous

I realise that in the PC version this is probably a simple key binding; this question is specific to the Xbox one version of Elite: Dangerous, only.

I recently added a chaff launcher to my ship. I can fire it by adding it to a fire group, switching over to that group and pulling one of the triggers, but this is a pain in a firefight.

However the chaff always appears on the far left of the HUD, even when not assigned to a trigger - does this mean that there's some other way to fire it?

Can I fire chaff without binding it to a specific fire group?

Does that also apply to other manually applied modules (head sinks, shield cells, etc)?

Comment: While your problem appears Xbox specific, simply having "I'm playing on Xbox" in your body is sufficient. The Xbox tag is exclusive to problems concerning the hardware and the console, not too games played on the console.

Comment: @Timelord64 do you have a meta citation for that? If that's the case then shouldn't there be platform specific game tags?

Comment: According to [info about xbox one keybindings on their support site](https://support.frontier.co.uk/kb/faq.php?id=133), there's no button for that by default. What if you hold down B to get the "ship context menu"? Also, looks like there's an option to fully customize the controller setup... Before I got a HOTAS, I used a controller pad and used a layout with "shift" keys, similar to this: http://postimg.org/image/41dkthnbn/ which allows access to much more controls (but has a higher learning curve).

Comment: @Keith, there are several meta answers for stuff like this. The general response is "remove the tags, unless that's all you do", but this is quite often to prevent old questions been bumped to the top, which was not the case in this situation. Ultimately, if the two versions of the game **differ enough** they do get their own tag. eg [tag:terraria] [tag:terraria-console]. When they don't differ that much, simply having "I'm playing on [platform] in the body is the accepted alternative.

Comment: taken from the Arqade Xbox 360 tag wiki: ***This tag should only be used if the question is about the Xbox One operating system or hardware, or a game feature truly unique to the Xbox One.***  

While the buttons are different, you would not be able to make the comparison to computer if it was a truly unique feature

Comment: I believe the tag was correct, the question is specific to the Xbox One as its controller-only input does not allow all the features from the PC version. Hence, any answer will likely target the Xbox version only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the *Horizons* update, **you are now able to bind chaff to a button mapping outside a fire group**, along with a shield cell bank.

To enable this, go to the Options menu via the game's main menu or the pause menu. Then go to Options > Controls > Miscellaneous. After expanding the Misc menu you should see the options listed:

[image: controls]

Comment: Thanks - seems like i could use Y+RB or Y+LB without giving up too much

Answer (score 1):

**No!**

Unlike in the PC version, you cannot bind Chaff, Heat Sinks, etc, to unique buttons. Hence you must use Fire Groups to use all these utilities.

The UI feature you are talking about are the Weapon Brackets. The additional brackets where you are seeing your Chaff Launcher and other utility-mounted devices on are called Secondary Brackets. In the Xbox One version of the game they are only useful for seeing cooldown timers and remaining ammunition as button bindings are not available.

Source: [Elite: Dangerous online manual](http://hosting.zaonce.net/manual/elite-xbox/index.html) page 52 and onwards.